# SQL query: Extra line with no data

Tags: sql

I´m trying to get the first 10 records when concatenating two strings, counting the number of records for these, and getting the average duration of the trips. The query jeeps showin the first line of the results with no data (maintaining the "to" in the route column, and null duration) what it affects the results... How can I get rid of that first zero line? (There are no empty fields in de database, so I do not know Why this line pops)

```
SELECT usertype,
  CONCAT(start_station_name," to ",end_station_name) AS route, 
  COUNT(*) AS num_trips, 
  ROUND(AVG(CAST(tripduration AS INT64)/60),2) AS duration
FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips` 
GROUP BY start_station_name, end_station_name, usertype
ORDER BY num_trips DESC
LIMIT 10
```

[query output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Afjq.png)

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on DBfiddle.com so that we can look at it?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks that your FROM table has plenty of empty rows.
And as there is no WHERE clause in your query they are also picked and counted.

Try that Query:

```
SELECT usertype,
  CONCAT(start_station_name," to ",end_station_name) AS route, 
  COUNT(*) AS num_trips, 
  ROUND(AVG(CAST(tripduration AS INT64)/60),2) AS duration
FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips` 
WHERE usertype != '' AND start_station_name != '' AND end_station_name != ''
GROUP BY start_station_name, end_station_name, usertype
ORDER BY num_trips DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: It worked! I´m learning SQL, please explain the solution: WHERE usertype != '' AND start_station_name != '' AND end_station_name != ''...

Comment: WHERE clause is limiting the number of rows that your query is operating on.
In that case your SELECT operation has been limited to rows where usertype, start_station_name and  end_station_name ain't empty. SQL operator != means "not equal", and two quotation marks with nothing between represents empty string.